# Creating a Neural Network for Classification in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to do classification using neural network and I have written the following code. Is this the code required to perform the training and classification?

```
%n1 to s5(n1=147,n2=205,n3=166,n4=204,n5=167,b1=156,b2=172,b3=153,b4=151,b5=160,r1=133,r2=135,r3=190,r4=143,ru1=133,ru2=153,ru3=154,ru4=137,s1=132,165,130,136,148)
%code: 
T = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,ru1,ru2,ru3,ru4,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5];
    x = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4];
    net1 = newff(minmax(T),[30 20 1],{'logsig','logsig','purelin'},'trainrp');
    net1.trainParam.show = 1000;
    net1.trainParam.lr = 0.04;
    net1.trainParam.epochs = 7000;
    net1.trainParam.goal = 1e-5;
    [net1] = train(net1,T,x);
     save net1 net1
```

Additionally, if I have more samples with more features then how should I represent it in T and X? How do I write T and x? For example:

```
sample 1 ..... 123 0.56 78 127 .......0 
sample 2 .......127 0.89 56 132 ........0 
sample3...... 134 0.72 65 140...1 
sample4 156 0.55 69 145 .....1 
sample 5 112 0.10 12 120 .......2 
sample 6 123 0.15 24 99 .......2 
sample 7 95 0.32 98 198 ....3 
sample 8 90 0.45 90 200...... 3
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Ethaan The question is fully answered and is about to be accepted so no, don't vote off-topic. Additionally, there's a MUCH larger presence for this question on SO than codereview which results in the user getting an answer faster. I honestly don't see the point of these subdomains.

Comment: @krisdestruction I can't find the question in this question. Wouldn't that put it in for `unclear what you're asking`?

Comment: No, the question is still salvageable. It would merit a comment to ask the OP to clarify.

Comment: Which I did, I'll edit the question appropriately

Comment: @Mast You'll see the changes when they're accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your solution appears correct. I should note, `newff` is obsolete as of R2010b NNET 7.0 and it's last used in R2010a NNET 6.0.4. The recommended function is now is feedforwardnet. The feedforwardnet implementation should be as follows

```
net = feedforwardnet([30 20]);
net.layers{1:2}.transferFcn = 'logsig'
net.trainParam.show = 1000;
net.trainParam.lr = 0.04;
net.trainParam.epochs = 7000;
net.trainParam.goal = 1e-5;

[net1] = train(net1,T,x);


save net1 net1
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with `minmax` but that should be the basic structure of the feedforward NN.

To structure `T` and `x`, say you have the following data:

```
[123 0.56 78 127] belongs to class 1
[127 0.89 56 132] belongs to class 1
[134 0.72 65 140] belongs to class 2
[156 0.55 69 145] belongs to class 2
[112 0.10 12 120] belongs to class 3
[123 0.15 24 99] belongs to class 3
```

You can set T and x as follows:

```
T = [ 123 0.56 78 127; 127 0.89 56 132; 134 0.72 65 140; 156 0.55 69 145; 112 0.10 12 120; 123 0.15 24 99];
x = [1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3];
```

Comment: @ChaithraKs Technically T should be a column vector and another feature is put as an additional column in the matrices `T` and `x`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sir if I have more samples with more features then how should I represent it in T and X. for example -* sample 1 ..... 123 0.56 78 127 .......0        *sample 2 .......127 0.89 56 132 ........0       *sample3...... 134 0.72 65 140...1        *sample4  156 0.55 69 145 .....1      *sample 5   112 0.10 12 120 .......2   *sample 6 123 0.15 24 99 .......2   * sample 7 95 0.32 98 198 ....3   *sample 8  90 0.45 90 200...... 3       How do I write T and x

Comment: `T = [1 1 1 1; 2 2 2 2];` If `[1 1 1 1 ]` is from the same dataset.

Comment: What I meant is there are four features for each sample,totally six samples are there and 3 classes: [123 0.56 78 127] belongs to class 1;                                                [127 0.89 56 132] belongs to class 1,                                                      [134 0.72 65 140] belongs to class 2 ,[156 0.55 69 145] belongs to class 2,                                                                                              [112 0.10 12 120] belongs to class 3,                                                     [123 0.15 24 99] belongs to class 3, how do I write T and x then

Comment: sir do we have to do validation check?   My neural will stop whenever the error is less than 1e-5 or else whenever it reaches max epoch i.e 7000.. Is that correct? If it reaches 7000 how can train the network?

Comment: currently I am using 26 inputs and four outputs. like wise 73 samples am giving and epochs I have given is 7000 ....is that correct

Comment: Yes this is correct, although you can consider increasing the epoch count if you find that the network is undertrained. So when training a NN, it will either stop when the error threshold is reached (1e-5) or when the epoch limit (7000) using 'trainlm' as the default training method. According to the [default ratios in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/divide-data-for-optimal-neural-network-training.html), it should take 70% of the data for training, 15% for validation, 15% for testing.

Comment: Do we have to write special code line for validation check ???.Once I run the code only train performance plot I can see

Comment: Check this article for how to analyze training performance after training
http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/analyze-neural-network-performance-after-training.html

Comment: If you take the boilerplate code from `nnstart`, there are a few built in functions to analyze the testing for you.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html